# Matrix "dimensional analysis" of Lagrangians in QFT

Tags: quantum-field-theory, tensor-calculus, dimensional-analysis, yang-mills, dirac-matrices

Since the important things in the QFT Lagrangian are vectors and matrices, I wanted to do a "matrix dimensional analysis" of each term.

The electromagnetic Lagrangian (ignoring *all* constants and signs) is :

$\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi + \bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\partial^{\mu}A_{\mu}\psi + \bar{\psi}\psi + F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$

Since $\psi$ is a (4x1) vector, $\bar{\psi}$ is (1x4), and **each** $\gamma^\mu$ is (4x4), the first term is :
(1x4)(4x4)(4x1) = (1x1) or a scalar.

Since $A_{\mu}$ for a given $\mu$ is a scalar, the second term is :
(1x4)(4x4)(1x1)(4x1) = (1x1), a scalar.

The third term is :
(1x4)(4x1) = (1x1)

And because of the summations in the fourth term, the two (4x4) terms collapse into a scalar as well.

The problem I'm having is with the QCD Lagrangian :

$\bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\partial_{\mu}\psi + \bar{\psi}\gamma^{\mu}\lambda\cdot A_{\mu}\psi + \bar{\psi}\psi + F_{\mu\nu}^aF^{a\mu\nu}$

Now, $\psi$ is primarily a 4-vector spinor, so it's still (4x1) (which it must be in order to be multiplied by the $\gamma$'s).  So the first and third terms don't change at all.

But the $\lambda$'s are 3x3 color matrices, and it was clarified [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/555696/what-is-the-qcd-gluon-field-mathematically) that **each** $A_\mu$ is a 3x3 matrix, which makes sense if they're to be multiplied together.  And I'm assuming $\lambda\cdot A_{\mu}$ = $\lambda_aA^a_\mu$ (a=1..8) is still a 3x3 matrix (a "weighted sum", if you will, of each $A_\mu$).

So then the second term looks like :
(1x4)(4x4)(3x3)(3x3)(4x1), which does not work.

Now, I understand that $\psi$ in QCD is a Dirac spinor of the quark field, so some component of $\psi$ must represent the colors $[\psi^r \psi^b \psi^g]^T$.  But even if $\psi$ represents a color vector in the third term, there's still the 4x4 $\gamma$'s.

**Question 1** : what is the resolution to this? How can $\psi$ represent both a spinor and color space in the same equation?  And is it only in the third term that $\psi$ represents the color space? (Ok, questions 1-3 :)

Regarding the $F_{\mu\nu}$ term, since it is created from the $A_\mu$ term, is it a 4x4 matrix **of** 3x3 matrices?  If so, the summations over $\mu$ and $\nu$ (0..3) would still leave a 3x3 matrix.

**Question 2** : what is the resolution to this? Is there an implied summation over the color matrices? Or something else?

**What I would most appreciate is the QCD Lagrangian, with both spinor and color indices included in every variable.**

*(edited to correct mistakes pointed out below)*

Comment: Your question dramatizes that you do not understand the notation when indices are suppressed. Write your elliptical expressions correctly by retaining spinor and color indices, and observe the index saturation systematics. Only *then* suppress indices.

Comment: Thank you. I have read many many lectures on QCD, and I have yet to find one that explicitly shows ALL the indices, which is exactly **why** I don't understand the notation when indices are suppressed. Perhaps you could write down the formula with all indices present?

Comment: *So then the third term looks like...* I think you mean the *second* term.

Comment: Your second term in each Lagrangian has three $\mu$’s. It should have only two.

Comment: Related: [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/422176/missing-identity-element-in-the-clifford-relation/422196#422196) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/430938/can-we-visualize-the-standard-model-fermions-as-a-5-dimensional-matrix-with-only/430941#430941).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the case of QCD $\psi$ has both a spinor and a color index. If you put all appropriate indices on everything you will see how it works.

Edit: Answer extended after a comment from OP.

Let $\mu, \nu, \cdots=0, \cdots, 3$ be Lorentz indices, $\alpha,\beta, \cdots = 1,\cdots, 4 $ spinor indices, $a,b,\cdots = 1,\cdots ,8$ indices for the generators of the Lie algebra  ($su(3)$ for QCD) and $r,s,\cdots = 1,2,3$ be the indices for the $\bf{3}$ representation of $su(3)$.

We then have $\psi_{\alpha \, r}$ for the spinor,  $(\lambda^a)_{rs}$ is an element a generator, $A_{\mu a}$ is the gauge field. These are now all $1\times 1$ in your notation.

As an example
$$
\bar{\psi} \gamma^\mu \lambda \cdot A_\mu \psi = \psi^\dagger_{\alpha r} (\gamma^0)_{\alpha\beta} (\gamma^\mu)_{\beta\delta}(\lambda^a)_{rs} A_{\mu a} \psi_{\delta s}
$$
As you see all indices are contracted. The $\partial_\mu$ should not be present in that term. I trust you can fill in the rest.

Comment: Thanks!  I have read many many lectures on QCD, and I have yet to find one that explicitly shows ALL the indices, that's why I don't understand the notation when indices are suppressed.  Perhaps you could write down the formula with all indices present?

Comment: @ZenFox42 I have extended the answer to give more details. Assuming this is what you need, can you pls accept the answer?

Comment: Thank you very much for doing that!  The $\partial_\mu$ was a carryover from a copy-and-paste of the first term.